# What do the file icons mean?

Tags: textmate

In TextMate, when I open all files from one directory up at once from the Terminal

```
mate ./directory/*
```

there are icons next to the file list/TOC on the right like so
[image] [image]

What do these icons mean? Specifically, what does the gray minus mean on the bottom? Or the red x, and possibly sometimes a green icon. Is there a reference for these icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are used to track the changes in files or you can say it's `git status` in file browser. The changes are tracked w.r.t **.git** directory in your project folder. If you remove that, the icons won't be visible.

These icons represent the un-committed changes:

- **Gray Circle**: It's usually only on directory and it means that the directory has some new files along with existing ones. Note that, along with new files, it can also include changes made to existing files.
- **Blue Circle**: It can be on a file or directory. It means that some changes are made to the existing file(s). The circle is auto applied to parent directory too.
- **Gray Minus**: Means the directory or file is new. So, a Gray Minus icon on a directory mean that it is new including the files in it. A Gray Circle on a directory mean that it has new files with Gray Minus in it.
- **Red Cross**: Shown when a file is deleted

Please check with the attached screenshot. Hope this helps [image]

I didn't come across the green icon yet. Please share the screenshot of that too.

**NOTE**: I've considered git here, but text mate supports other SCM's too.